# cannot set property of null while cross domain only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, cross-domain

I build a small app using the generator of HotTowel.
Then i build the app, config a port forwarding so i can have access from remote.
Checked on remote and is loading!
But i get this error: "cannot set property 'value' of null" - and of course the value of the table (for example) not showing.
This is happening only in other domain - on remote machine, in local it's work perfect!

At first i though, this is about the build operation,
maybe something with the Uglify/Minify but then again, in local it's working so i think it's something with other domain configuration.

Here is my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

var member = require('./api/member');

app.use('/api/member', member);

app.use(express.static('./build/'));

// Any deep link calls should return index.html
app.use('/*', express.static('./build/index.html'));

app.listen(4000);
console.log('Submit GET or POST to http://localhost:4000');
```

Comment: Finally i found my problem.

Comment: Forgot to change path to server on client, so no wonder it was working only in local..